# Can not open include file; no such file or dir

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I created new solution and new project (further A), added another external project (further B) `Right click -> add existing project`. Now, I have two projects (A & B) in my solution. I added also `additional dirs` to project A in order to it can see headers of project B. Then I added a few imports in file or project A from project B.

Then if I make right click on project B -> Rebuild it is built without any errors, then if I make right click on project B -> Rebuild I got an error that says :

```
1>------ Build started: Project: _DecoderEngine, Configuration: Release x64 ------
1>TetStreamDecoder.cpp
1>D:\land\co_main\_Infrastructure\Tier1.0\_FileCodec\_Decoder\_IDecoderCallback.h(3): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: '_Shared/_FileTypes.h': No such file or directory
1>Done building project "_DecoderEngine.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 2 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

What is weird that a file where I got an error it is a file from project B, it means if I make right click on project B -> Rebuild it is ok, but if I try rebuild project A that has import from B I got and error in files from project B...

What am I doing wrong? I feel like I miss something in configuration, maybe should I add something to `Liker` or something else?

**EDIT**

tree looks like this

```
FileCodec
  |
  -_DecoderEngine (project A)
  |
  -_Decoder (project B)
  |
  -_Shared
```

FYI - project A use project B and project B use Shared

Then, dependencies I have added to `C\C++ -> Additional dirs` to project A are :

```
../_Decoder
../_Shared
```

Looks ok, because Decoder engine reside on the same level in tree as dependency, so we need to go one level up and here you are.

Comment: Where is `_Shared/_FileTypes.h` on your file system? What directories did you add as additional dirs?

Comment: @john edited my question

Comment: The additional include dir is `".."`

Comment: The problem is that `_Shared` is being mentioned twice `../_Shared` and `Cannot open include file: '_Shared/_FileTypes.h'` so the compiler is looking for a file `../_Shared/_Shared/_FileTypes.h` which doesn't exist. As Hans said, it should probably be `..`.